# I have a question how to add input fields values with same name into the database using entity framework? Below is my code,

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my HomeWithIndentityController

```
namespace MVC.CRUDDynamicFormTest.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeWithIndentityController : Controller
        {
            // GET: HomeWithIndentity
            public ActionResult WithIndex()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult GetData()
            {
                using (DynamicCRUDDatabase2Entities db = new DynamicCRUDDatabase2Entities())
                {
                    List<DynamicCRUDTable2> dynamicCRUDTable2s = db.DynamicCRUDTable2.ToList<DynamicCRUDTable2>();
                    return Json(new { data = dynamicCRUDTable2s }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Add(int id = 0)
            {

                return View(new DynamicCRUDTable2());

            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Add(DynamicCRUDTable2 obj)
            {
                using (DynamicCRUDDatabase2Entities db = new DynamicCRUDDatabase2Entities())
                {


                    db.DynamicCRUDTable2.Add(obj);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { succces = true, message = "saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my entity model class

```
public partial class DynamicCRUDTable2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

This my View

```
<form action="~/HomeWithIndentity/Add" method="POST" onsubmit="return Submitform(this)">
            <input data-val="true" id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" />
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="FirstName[]" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" name="FirstName[]" class="form-control" />
            <br />
            <br />

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-danger" />
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="~/Home/Index">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

In the above view i want to add the firstname input field values to the Database dynamicallly.but it does not working can you let me know why?What errors i have done.
does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: can you help @pawan Bastola?